# Get user ip behind behind anonymous proxy

Tags: javascript, php, proxy, actionscript, ip

In our intranet the users access to web server via an anonymous proxy that not be able to send `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. Is there way to get real `ip` address on users using javascript, or actionscript(flash), or another way that my web application access the window api functions? all users use Firefox browser. Is there a configuration in Apache solve this problem?

Comment: Since you are talking about intranet, I presume the users are employees of some sort. You could create a firefox plugin to detect the local IP address and provide that to the server. Some more info here and working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is unfortunately the best chance of successfully identifying client IP address behind an anonymous proxy.

You could also try these headers below to attempt to identify client's real IP.

`HTTP_VIA 
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR 
HTTP_X_FORWARDED
HTTP_FORWARDED 
HTTP_CLIENT_IP
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP 
VIA
X_FORWARDED_FOR 
FORWARDED_FOR
X_FORWARDED FORWARDED
CLIENT_IP
FORWARDED_FOR_IP
HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION`