# How to know IP Lan request client in python?

Tags: python, django, ip, lan

Is there a way to know the lan IP request client?.
I am work in django, I tried this:

```
 def get_ip_test():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 0))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP
```

But this return IP from server, I saw in javascript an example to get LAN IP
[example javascript](http://net.ipcalf.com/)

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.connect(('8.8.8.8',0))
>>> s.getsockname()[0]
'192.168.10.2'
```

Comment: Its work, but if you put on a server web ( web.com/get_ip ), you get the Public IP from client.

Comment: Can you better define which IP you are trying to obtain? It sounds like you have a django server and several web clients. Do you want 1) django server LAN IP 2) django server public IP 3) client LAN IP 4) client public IP?

Comment: Unfortunately the client's LAN IP is not available by querying a standard socket. 
Web servers in general do not have access their clients' LAN IP,  although [a new HTML5 extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26850789/7089847) just added support for obtaining it.

Comment: To clarify my last comment: you can do something custom, such as writing client-side code (javascript) to get the local IP and post it to the server.

Comment: thanks solar, for the moment WebRTC  works only in firefox and chrome.