# Local IP Address of Client in same LAN as the Server

Tags: ip-address, static-ip-address

I have a website where I want to know the local IP address of clients that are accessing my website from within the LAN. There already exists such a website in our network but the owner refuses to reveal the technology as of now. So I know it is possible. I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20194722/2109808). This question demands to know the local IP from outside the network, which has its own limitations. However I want to know how to do it everytime if both client and server are in same LAN (without depending on the client's browser to support WebRTC).

Additional info:
I use nginx on my server and my backend runs on node.js
Thanks in advance. :D