# How can I detect if a user is inside a corporate network using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a website where I want to display a link **ONLY** for users inside our local corporate network.

Therefore I have to detect this using Javascript.

I've tried to "ping" a test website hosted on one of our local IIS server with Ajax, but my website is using **HTTPS** so it does not work (as it seems impossible to issue a SSL certificate for a local server) as all recent browsers raise a "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error.

Does anyboby have a clue or an idea on how I can do that?

Here is my current test (which does not work...)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://my-local-website.com",
    timeout: 3000,
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    success: function (response, textS, xhr) { 
         $('body').html('true');
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $('body').html('false');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need SSL for testing? (You can create a certificate for localhost, but you'll need to either run your own CA or use command line tools and a self signed certificate. In the latter case manually adding to the browser's certificate store as trusted.)

Comment: you can get clients IP address and check if it's same as yours or thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this topic to get the function that can determine the current IP of the user.

> [Can You Get A Users Local LAN IP Address Via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript)

And then you use substring or any string method that you prefer to get some parts of the local IP that match with your local corporate network. For example, 192.167.*.*