# Mac address of router or adapter

Tags: mac-address

Hope someone can enlighten me. I have been wondering if the mac address visible to other sites using javascript is the mac address of router or the adapter in my pc or laptop? I am aware that the router strips my adapter's mac address and just sends the info to and fro the web. Thanks

Comment: Yes or no - it depends on the situatuion.

Comment: can you explain the situations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, so I'll make a larger answer.

You can not get MAC addresses from Javascript in a browser. You can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript).

If you meant IP address, then you can get all the computer IP addresses (usually referred as "private IP addresses" when you are behind a router) using WebRTC. You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript) and this [site](http://www.whatsmyip.org/more-info-about-you/).

You can also get a visible IP address (usually referred as public IP in most cases) by querying a remote server, as [this one](https://ifconfig.co/ip).

Comment: Saw the thread. What is activeX? Do all windows systems have it?

Comment: Not sure I can do better than this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX

Comment: okay thanks. It's over my head to understand this stuff. My fault I'm not a techy.