# Secure, local IoT Device Discovery using PWA without a remote server

Tags: progressive-web-apps, iot

I'm looking for a way to managing and controlling IoT devices without the (constant) need for a remote server to be part in it and with a PWA instead of a native application on the managing device. The resulting goal is an IoT device that keeps working when a product eventually goes obsolete (no more server running/allocated) and having an application that has PWA benefits like always up-to-date, easy to replicated and cheaply hosted on something like S3.

As an example, let's say I have one or more IoT devices of different classes like an ESP8266 and a Raspberry Pi for instance. Just as with any new IoT device I want to add it to the network and from there on manage its state from an app. The app in this case is a PWA instead of full blown native app.

1) Traditionally, in the initial setup a native app would scan for wifi networks, connecting automatically to one that has the right name. Using PWA's we are limited to just the "[state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API)" of the network. So users would have to manually switch to the network of the newly connected IoT device. This is okay.

2) Next up, the user would need to enter his/her wifi credentials. There might be methods to set this up automatically using a native app, but I don't believe this is the case on a PWA. This, also, is okay.

3) The device then restarts, tries to connect to the network set up in (2). If set up correctly it should get its IP using DHCP. And now things get difficult. I want to 'discover' that network from my PWA. There used to be a way to retrieve the IP from a device using the [WebRTC API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript). but that since has changed to show an [obfuscated mdns](http://net.ipcalf.com/) that resolves to localhost. The ip leak would have allowed for a browser based network scan, but that is no longer possible. I always hoped that Android would default to using a users router as a DNS server, but that is not the case. The result is that simply using an mDNS isn't an option either. I do not want user having to check their router, install an app like fing or do anything else that disrupts the flow from a UX perspective.

Step (3) needs to run every time the app starts so you'd want something reliable. **Scanning for devices isn't possible using a PWA, so I need to find another method.** I was thinking of something like the way Docker containers can find each other in between networks (see etcd for example), using a predefined key that is shared during installation. The problem with this, is that it requires a remote server to store the IPs attached to that key. I don't want that.

Ideas on how to solve this are very much appreciated! I want to be able to offer a solution that would work even when WAN is out. That being said, I am aware that a connection to a remote server is needed if the end user would want to enable any voice assistant or wants to control a device from WAN.

Comment: I found this exploit that could be used... But itt an exploit,  so that's a no go... https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/9erchs/local_host_discovery_in_browser/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Hi @Wouter! were you able to find a good solution for this? I have a similar challenge

Comment: It seems to be working on Android 12, but that's about it: https://blog.esper.io/android-dessert-bites-26-mdns-local-47912385/